# extjs store: sum field where acct = 12345

Tags: extjs, sum, where-clause, store

I am trying to sum a particular field in my extjs store WHERE accountNumber = 'x'.
Right now I am looping through and I'm wondering if there is a faster way.
Something like 
var sum = grid.getStore().sum('NameColumn').where('acct') = 12345;

this is how I am doing it now...

```
        for (var i = 0; i < listCount; i++) {

        sum = 0;
        singleAccount = accountList[i];            

        //go through calc store, sum pnl column
        calculatedPositionsDataStore.each(function (record) {
            var tempAcctNum = record.get('AcctNum');
            if (tempAcctNum === singleAccount)
            {
                tempAcctDesc = record.get('AcctShortCode');
                tempTradeLevel = record.get('TradingLevel');
                var pnl = record.get('CalcPLSett');

                sum = sum + pnl;
            }
        }, this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that's faster than iterating over the whole list, but there's something that's far less to code for you:

```
var sum = calculatedPositionsDataStore.query("AcctNum", singleAccount).sum("CalcPLSett");
```

Under the hood, this acts similar to your code, but it's far more readable and reuseable.

So, what's happening here?

- `store.query` gives you a `MixedCollection` containing only those entries where a certain property matches a certain value. You could easily write more complex matching functions if you use `queryBy`. To generate this Collection, it runs over all records in the store.
- The MixedCollection has a method `sum`, which takes a property name and then iterates over all records in the collection and sums the named property.

So it *may* even be some nanoseconds slower than your code, but if you need it often, in different parts of the code, you save bytes on the wire.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation.  I will be using it often but if you think its nanoseconds slower than I should probably take the easier less code approach.  nanoseconds most likely won't be an issue.  thanks!